# Not persisting messages when the system comes up in the wrong order

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

We're sending messages to Apache Camel using RabbitMQ.

We have a "sender" and a Camel route that processes a RabbitMQ message sent by the sender.

We're having deployment issues regarding which end of the system comes up first.

Our system is low-volume. I am sending perhaps 100 messages at a time. The point of the message is to reduce 'temporal cohesion' between a thing happening in our primary database, and logging of same to a different database. We don't want our front-end to have to wait.

The "sender" will create an exchange if it does not exist.

The issue is causing deployment issues.

Here's what I see:

If I down the sender, down Camel, delete the exchange (clean slate), start the sender, then start Camel, and send 100 messages, the system works. (I think because the sender has to be run manually for testing, the Exchange is being created by the Camel Route...)

If I clean slate, and send a message, and then up Camel afterwards, I can see the messages land in RabbitMQ (using the web tool). No queues are bound. Once I start Camel, I can see its bound queue attached to the Exchange. But the messages have been lost to time and fate; they have apparently been dropped.

If, from the current state, I send more messages, they flow properly.

I think that if the messages that got dropped were persisted, I'd be ok.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you deleting the exchange? Are exchanges,queues and messages durable?

Comment: @cantSleepNow Deleting the exchange is indeed a bad idea. We were doing it manually just trying to get messages to flow. We won't be doing that under normal circumstances.

Comment: In general, if you have flow problems, that usually means that the queues are "flooded" that is - the broker cannot keep up with publishers, so it limits the rate in which the msgs are "sent" (publisher -> broker). You could increase the number of consumers, and eventually the queues will free up. https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/

Comment: `If we manually delete the exchange after Camel comes up, the Sender will make a new one with the old name. But the Camel route will never see messages being sent to this exchange` Of course, because once you delete the exchange the binding is lost. So after creating the new exchange (with old exchange name) you'd need to re-bind. Regarding message durability - bad terminology on my side, meant to say message persistence. EDIT Just to add the link for persistence config https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html

Comment: Ok, now I'm reading again the question with edits - this part `All our messages are important, and I would prefer that if there is no consumer, the messages stay there until the consumer starts.` This is exactly what may cause the broker to slow down extremely (see my first comment) I dare say that it's now the way it's meant to be used - as a long-term buffer.

Comment: @cantSleepNow I inherited the issue, and am learning more. This may be a bad question. I am going to change the question instead of making a new one since you're the only participant.  One moment please.

Comment: No worries, I like the question :)

Comment: @cantSleepNow there you go. My head is clearer so I think the question has less noise in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's hard to say what exactly is wrong, but I'll try and provide some pointers.

You should set up [all exchanges and queues to be durable](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html), and the messages persistent. You should never delete any of these entities (unless they are empty and you no longer use them) and maybe look at them as tables in a database. It's your infrastructure of sorts, and as with database, you wouldn't want that the first DB client to create a table that it needs (this of course applies to your use case, at least that's what it seems to me).
In the comments I mentioned *flow state* of the queue, but with 100 messages this will probably never happen.

Regarding message delivery - persistent or not, the broker (server) keeps them until they are consumed with **acknowledgment** that's sent back by the consumer (in lot's of APIs this is done automatically but it's actually one of the most important concepts).

If the exchange to which the messages were published is deleted, they are gone. If the server gets killed or restarted and the messages are persisted - again, they're gone. There may as well be some more scenarios in which messages get dropped (if I think of some I'll edit the answer).

If you don't have control over creating *(declaring* usually in the APIs) exchanges and queues, than (aside from the fact that's it's not the best thing IMHO) it can be tricky since declaring those entities is idempotent, i.e. you can't create a durable queue q1 , if a non durable queue with the same name already exists. This could also be a problem in your case, since you mention the *which part of the system comes first* thing - maybe something is not declared with same parameters on both sides...

Comment: I cannot confirm that, without a consumer, the messages sent are retained. They seem to go to the bit-bucket.  If the sender creates and binds a queue then they are delivered to that queue. But as of now, I can't make my camel route use that queue. So those messages are inert.

Comment: I think the messages being dropped are a well-documented pub-sub feature. The exchange is a fan-out.